# Loop through object in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How do I access the data in each of object when Laravel has structured it like this, I need to convert it to a normal array.

[image]

I need to retrieve the "id", "created_at", etc, etc

Normal array:

[image]

This is my attempt

```
$results = array();

    foreach($object as $obj=>$key) {
        array_push($results, $obj);
    }

    return $results;
```

Comment: This looks like JSON. Try `$results = json_decode($object, true)`;

Comment: @foreach($objects as $index=>$key)
<td>{{$key->id}}</td>
<td>{{$key->createddate}}</td>
@endforeach

Comment: Beautiful thankyou @Sona

Comment: worked @JoshuaNissenbaum if worked then rate up..welcome..

Comment: I used the laravel db "get()" method which returned a collection of objects as JSON data and EddyTheDove advice in the comment above worked to turn the JSON into an array of data which can than be manipulated by Laravels built in helper fuctions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Try this..

@foreach($objects as $index=>$key) 
<td>{{$key->id}}</td>
<td>{{$key->createddate}}</td>
 @endforeach
```